# How can I know if a jenkins build has started in Python?

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-cli

I wrote a script in Python where I launch a Jenkins build via cli :

```py
import subprocess
command = "curl -s -X POST  http://<user>:<token>@<server>/build"
subprocess.Popen(command)
```

I need to find a way to check the build status like :

```
If not started : Wait to start
If started : on progress
If ended : Success / Failure
```

by doing :

```py
while True:
    # Check the status of the build
    # ... <----- I don't know what to do here

    if STATUS == "on progress"
        break
```

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: maybe use this --> https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Why are you using python to launch a remote Jenkins build? You could login manually to Jenkins and build the job.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this endpoint:

http://my-jenkins.com/job/job_name/lastBuild/api/json

Check this link to view the python implementation:

https://serverfault.com/a/309917/490115

Comment: exact answer and the latter link is useful too